# Getting fields from superclass

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the following abstract class:

```
 abstract class Customer
{
    private string address { get; set; }
    private int phone { get; set; }

    public Customer(string address, int phone)
    {
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Then i have the following class that inherits from the customer class:

```
   class Private : Customer
{

    private string name { get; set; }
    private int age { get; set; }
    private string sex { get; set; }

    public Private(string name, int age, string sex, string address, int phone) : base(address, phone)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
```

My question is: How do I access the phone and address fields on my Private class?

Comment: Make them public.

Comment: Oh god, I feel so stupid. Thanks for the quick reply...

Comment: You can access them from the constructor just fine. If you want to access them from methods they need to be public or protected.

Comment: @Quantic What do you mean by accessing it from the constructor?

Comment: Right below `this.sex = sex` you can type, `address = "test"`, `this.name = address;`, i.e., you can access both its `get` and `set` accessors even though its private, but only from the derived classes constructor. If you want to do the same things from a method then it has to be protected or public. I should make it clear that I simply tested this and it worked, at the moment I can't find a MSDN page that explicitly says why you can do this. Maybe the derived constructor is actually scoped inside the base constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `protected` modifier instead of `private` for everything that can be accessed by inherited classes.

From the docs:

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I feel like I should have thought of this myself.